# Facebook Graph API : empty results when trying to reach leads on LeadgenForms

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently working on an app, with a system user that have access to both Page and AdAccount that I'm querying.
I got an access token with all the Permissions that I could query (because I had to try everything I could) :

*read_insights, publish_video, catalog_management, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_messaging, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, leads_retrieval, whatsapp_business_management, attribution_read, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, public_profile*

I am able to get all leadgen_forms, but then when I want to query the leads of these forms, the Facebook API sends me empty data arrays.

The code :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Connecteurs;


use App\Repository\ClientRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Facebook\Facebook;

class FacebookGraphConnecteur
{
    const APP_ID       = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
    const APP_SECRET   = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

    private $fb;

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->fb     = new Facebook(
            [
                'app_id'                => self::APP_ID,
                'app_secret'            => self::APP_SECRET,
                'default_access_token'  => self::ACCESS_TOKEN,
            ]
        );
        $this->em     = $em;
    }

    public function recupereLeads()
    {
        $clients_ids = $this->recupereFacebookAdsIdClients();

        foreach ($clients_ids as $client_ids) {
            $token = $this->fb->get("/{$client_ids['facebookAdsId']}?fields=access_token")->getGraphNode()->asArray();
            $response = $this->fb->get("/{$client_ids['facebookAdsId']}/leadgen_forms", $token['access_token']);
            $params['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
            $forms = $response->getDecodedBody()["data"];
            $leads = [];
            foreach ($forms as $form) {
                if ($form["status"] === "ACTIVE") {
                    $formId = $form['id'];

                    $leadsForm = $this->fb->get("/{$formId}/leads?fields=created_time,id,ad_id,form_id,field_data", self::ACCESS_TOKEN);
                    $leads[] = $leadsForm->getDecodedBody()["data"];
                }
            }
            var_dump($leads);
        }

    }

    private function recupereFacebookAdsIdClients()
    {
        $em = $this->em;
        /** @var ClientRepository $repo */
        $repo = $em->getRepository("App:Client");

        return $repo->recupereFacebookAdsId();
    }
}
```

The result :

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [3]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  //.... And so on
}
```

The `/<FORM_ID>/leads` endpoint give me 200 http code though :
[image]

I also tryed with the Business SDK, but got the same result :

```php
$leads[] = json_encode((new LeadgenForm($formId))->getLeads(
    $fields,
   $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I also saw that from the v.9.0, we could not get prospect if the app is in development mode (what it is), but I also saw that there were no development / live mod anymore... I'm really confused.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: The code looks good. Please double check the form contains data by requesting the field `leads_count` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/lead-gen-data/#parameters

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It does `$leadsForm = $this->fb->get("/{$formId}?fields=id,leads_count");` gives me results :   ```array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(15) "XXXX"
    ["leads_count"]=>
    int(33)
  }
```

Comment: Very strange... try with the API Explorer `/XXXX/leads`

Comment: Thanks again. I already try with the graph api explorer, and the results are the same : empty data array

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution? I am also getting empty array when I make a call to the following end point:
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/leads

Comment: Hi, the problem has not been answered yet... I will post here if we manage to solve this !

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to read all the leads from a leads form using PHP. After some digging I've discovered the following:

According to [Facebook Documentation for the marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/), starting from v9.0,  Dev Mode app users can only access leads submitted by someone with a role in that same app.

> Blockquote
> Starting in v9.0, you will not be able to retrieve leads if your app is in Dev Mode. For testing purposes, Dev Mode app users can access leads submitted by someone with a role in that same app. See App Roles. Apps in Live Mode continue to have access to all leads.

Use this tool to add test leads to your app: [Lead Ads Testing Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing). After adding a test lead to the form, the data array will return values.

According to the documentation apps in Live Mode continue to have access to all the leads in a form.